# moveCamera does not work

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have this onClick method inside an adapter

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
  // Clicked postion
  AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      int position = getAdapterPosition();
      PlaceSaved place = items.get(position);
      // Here is the data Do your stuff
      Snackbar.make(view, "Position is:"+place.getTitle()+","+place.getLongi(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      latlang.Lat = Double.parseDouble(place.getTitle());
      latlang.Lang = Double.parseDouble(place.getLongi());
      lStatus.LOCATION_STATUS_UPDATE = 1;

  Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
  view.getContext().startActivity(i);
  SecondFragment sf = new SecondFragment();
  sf.showMap();
    }
  });
}
```

The showMap method is defined as:

```
 public void showMap(){
    Log.e("ShowMap", "is called");
    if (marker != null) {
      marker.remove();
      mMap.clear();
    }
    if (mMap != null) {
      updateLocationUI();
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
          new LatLng(latlang.Lat, latlang.Lang), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
      marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(new LatLng(latlang.Lat, latlang.Lang))
          .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon))
      );
    }
    new SunFragment();
  }
```

with onclick, showMap is called properly and also the `sunFragment`,  method.
But this has no effect on mMap related methods e.g. moveCamera and marker.
They remain in the same position.

How I can move the camera? And more than that, why its not moving at all?

Comment: Can mMap be null? Did you tried debugging? If you didn't, try debugging first to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, mMap can be null, havnt debug, but without the null check, I got nullpointerexcption error